# Is There a Way to Customize The Text in Navigation Item Prompt?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is there any way that texts in navigation item prompt can be customized, like resizing the text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom view and use it, e.g. create UILabel and customize it like you want and set this label to the self.navigationItem.titleView property in the view controller class.

Comment: I though there is another way aside from using the titleView. :) Thanks!